# Create terms when registering taxonomy?

Tags: categories, taxonomy, slug

I'm registering taxonomy in my functions.php file:

```
register_taxonomy("our_gallery_types", array("gallery"), array("hierarchical" => true, "label" => "Categories", "singular_label" => "Category", "rewrite" => true));
```

And it works perfectly.

But I want also to automatically create two terms in this taxonomy, how would i do that?

When you run Wordpress for the very first time and click Posts there is "Uncategorized" category. I want to do exactly the same for my taxonomy, so my users won't get confused and won't have to create categories for their own.

How do i achieve that?

Comment: Updated the title to better describe the question being asked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use [wp_insert_term()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_term) (after you register the taxonomy)

You can also check if a [term exists()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/term_exists) before doing that, to save some useless db queries...

Comment: +1 and want to note that some kind of check is really necessary. While taxonomy registration is on the fly and in memory, terms are stored in database and should only be created once.

Comment: Can term_exists be called on every page load? Or should I be careful to only put it on like a setup page or plugin activation?